# deja dup freezes during restore

Tags: deja-dup

I bought a Dell Inspirion computer about a month ago and dual-booted it with windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04.  I used Deja Dup to make a daily backup of my files on an external drive.  The computer had hardware problems, so I returned it & exchanged it for the exact same model computer.  I was able to dual-boot Win10 and Ubuntu 16.04 without any problems.
Inside of Ubuntu, I did all of my updates, then attempted to restore my files using Deja-Dup.  No matter what I try, I can not get Deja-Dup to complete the Restore process without the computer freezing and needing to be re-booted.

I made the following variations in attempting to restore my files, but none of them worked:

1. I tried to change Ubuntu Kernels from the grub to load the OS, then restore my files --failed
2. I tried running ubuntu in recovery mode from grub, I checked the file system and confirmed everything is healthy, then re-booted into "SafeMode" upstart, all i got was a blank / black screen (most likely a minor, unrelated graphic card issue)  --failed
3. Instead restoring the files to the original locations, I tried to restore to a folder on the desktop, computer froze --failed

Anyone have any suggestions? Much appreciated. THX